# Explode items from a database field using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using an mvc framework, I stored three pictures for each property in my table. Now when the user selects a property, I want the three pictures to be displayed separately. I have already linked to my database table in my model page:

```
public function get_pictures($pick)
    {
        $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT other_img FROM property WHERE name = '$pick'");//pick is the property the user selects
    }
```

and my controller page has the function:

```
if(isset($_GET['pick'])){ 
            $pick = $_GET['pick'];
            $this->view->data['picture']=$this->model->get_pictures($pick);
    }
```

then on my view. I'm trying to implode the different pictures from the table and use them in a Bootstrap carousel:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<?php foreach ($picture as $key => $value) { $pix = explode(",", $value);?>
<div class="item active">
<img src="<?php echo URL.'public/'.'images/'.$pix[0]?>" alt="">
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="<?php echo URL.'public/'.'images/'.$pix[1]?>" alt="">
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="<?php echo URL.'public/'.'images/'.$pix[2]?>" alt="">
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

but its giving me error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: Start with `print_r($picture)`

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the return statement in the function `get_pictures($pick)`

```
public function get_pictures($pick)
 {
     $sth = $this->db->query("SELECT other_img FROM property WHERE name = '$pick'");

    return $sth;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is from a bad MYSQL query.

**Somthing to try:**

This is one of my favorite functions I keep it on the second line of my index (so its globally accessible).

```
// First step in debugging
function sortDump($mixed = null) {
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump(($mixed == null ? $GLOBALS : $mixed));
    echo '</pre>';
    exit(1);
}
```

You would use this by just placing the value you'd like to check as a parameter.

```
sortDump($this->model->get_pictures($pick)); // This my help the debug
```

I think we need to look at this to gain further incite. 
So post back, but first a personal critique...

Experienced PHP developers will use a shorthand version of:

```
<?php echo URL.'public/'.'images/'.$pix[2]?>
```

To =>

```
<?=URL .'public/images/'. $pix[2]?>
```